# explicit self adjoint operator which has no diagonalization

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, adjoint-operators

Let a linear operator $T : H \to H$ be diagonalizable if $H$ has an orthonormal basis composed of eigenvectors of $H$

Give an example of an explicit self adjoint operator which has no diagonalization and prove it has no diagonalization.

Considering $f(t)\to tf(t)$ can I some how show that it has no diagonalization because no orthonormal basis is composed of eigenvectors?

Any other direction?

Comment: You're apparently taking "diagonalization" to mean that the operator has a complete orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. And that's fairly standard. So, yes, all you need to show is that $(Mf)(t)=tf(t)$ has no eigenvectors on a space such as $L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: We say that a linear operator $T : H \to H$ is diagonalizable if H has an orthonormal basis composed of eigenvectors of $H$

Comment: To see why $(Mf)(t)=tf(t)$ has no eigenvectors on $L^2[0,1]$, suppose $Tf=\lambda f$. Then $\int_{0}^{1}|(t-\lambda)f(t)|^2dt=0$, which forces $(t-\lambda)f(t)=0$ a.e. and, hence, also $f(t)=0$ a.e..

Comment: And what would be an explicit example for such operator? Is $f(t)\to tf(t)$ enough?

Comment: Also why is it that $f(t)=$ a.e. shows $(Mf)(t)=tf(t)$?

Comment: I've explained: $Mf=\lambda f$ for some $\lambda$ implies $f(t)=0$ a.e. t, which means $f=0$ in $L^2[0,1]$. So that means $M$ has no eigenvalues.

Comment: Just to be clear a.e. means almost everywhere?

Comment: Yes, almost everywhere.